# Format specifier in Fortran

Tags: fortran77

Fortran question: Which is the correct format statement, format('CRDET',2i5,1p3e12.4) or format('CRDET',2i5,1p,3e12.4)? The difference is the comma separator between the last two arguments.

Comment: I would have thought it would be format('CRDET',2I5,3(1PE12.4)).  In both the cases specified, the scale factor isn't tied to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going out on a limb, reading standards but not testing it.. It seems both forms are the same and the P applies to all 3 of the E's

1) It (P) applies to all subsequently interpreted F, E, D, and G edit descriptors until another scale factor is encountered,

2) The comma used to separate list items in the list flist *may be omitted* as follows: 
  **  Between a P edit descriptor and an immediately following F, E, D, or G edit descriptor

I suppose the comma form is safer as its not clear if the repeated edit descriptor falls under point 2..

Comment: having tested it, gfortran indeed takes either form.